# Can not build a code in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

When I try to build a code,I get the following message in build log:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lbgi collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

the ld.exe is the linker executable, it links all the files together so a program can be made to run on your system and specs, if it says 'cannot fine xxx', it means you are trying to link against a file which the system can't find.

look on 
[mingw.org wiki: how to specify location of libs](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW)